# Node dependency/permission errors when installing expo-cli

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, command-line, npm-install

I am trying to install expo to use react native, using `npm install -g expo-cli` but I get huge error logs.

I tried to chown `/usr/local` using `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/* /usr/local` and `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local`  but I get `chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted`. I tried updating node and npm, deleting them, reinstalling them, updating with homebrew, installing expo-cli with homebrew. I tried sudo installing. I get similar errors. I tried `yarn add global expo-cli` and I got almost the exact same output that I got from  `npm install -g expo-cli` about the dependencies.

Here's the output I get in terminal from running `npm install -g expo-cli`:

```
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm WARN @expo/dev-tools@0.5.14 requires a peer of @expo/xdl@^53.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

When I try to use `yarn add` I get the same errors about dependencies but instead of the "npm ERR!" part I get:

```
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
info @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.4: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The platform "darwin" is incompatible with this module.
info "@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "expo-cli > @expo/dev-tools@0.5.14" has incorrect peer dependency "@expo/xdl@^53.8.0".
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/<username>/node_modules/.bin/detect-libc'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/<username>/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

When I run `sudo npm install -g expo-cli` I get the following:

```
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

> @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.4 preinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin
> node platform.js

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
path.js:1077
        path = process.cwd();
                       ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, uv_cwd
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1077:24)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:269:32)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
/usr/local/bin/expo-cli -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/usr/local/bin/expo -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js

> fsevents@1.2.9 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
path.js:1077
        path = process.cwd();
                       ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, uv_cwd
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1077:24)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:269:32)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

> iltorb@2.4.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
path.js:1077
        path = process.cwd();
                       ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, uv_cwd
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1077:24)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:269:32)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
sh: node-gyp: command not found
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied

> sharp@0.22.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
path.js:1077
        path = process.cwd();
                       ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, uv_cwd
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1077:24)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:269:32)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
sh: node-gyp: command not found
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Permission denied
npm WARN @expo/dev-tools@0.5.14 requires a peer of @expo/xdl@^53.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ts-pnp@1.1.2 requires a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.4 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.9.4: wanted {"os":"win32,linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.4 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.4 preinstall: `node platform.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iltorb@2.4.3 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/iltorb):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: iltorb@2.4.3 install: `node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! sharp@0.22.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.22.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I expected the output to say something like expo installed ok but instead it gives me the error logs about dependencies and permissions.

Comment: You must be under a proxy administration. Please try to run the installation as an admin. The error log also says it. Hope you have added http and https proxy to your cli

Comment: Do you mean running it with sudo? I added the error log I get from running ```sudo npm install -g expo-cli``` to the bottom of the main post above. I haven't added http or https proxy, do you have any links for how to do that?

Comment: do you mean like this? https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what worked but I reinstalled node via homebrew and again via the download from the node website and i deleted a node modules folder on my user folder and now it works, while still giving some warnings for the optional dependencies

Comment: For me it was because of the `-g` flag and npm wasn't installed globally on my system and I had to reinstall node using nvm and it installed without the permission error but still showed deprecated dependency warnings.

Answer (score 8):

You need to have super user access to install a package globally. Try:
`sudo npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: I never said it's the wrong way or only way. I don't know a way to install a package globally without `sudo`. But every time I included `sudo` to install a package globally, it worked, no question asked. If there is a "right" way, please let us know.

Comment: Yes, using sudo its installed globally, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use npx alternative of npm install.
I can't fix the error, but 
    $ npx expo init Awesomeproject
works.

The only disadvantage of using npx is taking more time than using preinstalled expo.
Try npx!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found, as this is related to some new permissions controls in macOS is to use option 2 here: https://github.com/mixonic/docs.npmjs.com/blob/master/content/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions.md

This changes your default home folder for global modules, which may require reinstallation of others when it’s time to update, but won’t affect those already installed.

Otherwise an unsafe method of doing it is:

> sudo npm i -g --unsafe-perm expo-cli